# How to also pause physics object before entering screen in corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, game-physics

I used `physics.pause()` and `physics.start()` , it works but my problem is that one function keeps displaying an object at the bottom and when I resume the game, those object are compiled and all of them enter screen at once. I hope someone can help me.

here's my code:

```
local isPaused = false

    function pausePhysics( event )
        if "began" == event.phase then
            if isPaused == false then
                physics.pause(lobo)
                isPaused = true
                    timer.pause(countDownTimer)

                    local decide = display.newImage("wood.png")
                        decide.x = display.contentWidth*0.5
                        decide.y = display.contentHeight*0.5
                    local yes
                    local no

                    local function oo()
                        if score == 0 then
                            onBackBtnRelease()
                        elseif score >0 and score <=10 then
                            GameOver1()
                        elseif score >10 and score <=20 then
                            GameOver2()
                        else
                            GameOver3()
                        end
                    end

                    yes = widget.newButton
                    {
                        defaultFile= "yes.png",
                        width=100, height=50,
                        onRelease = oo  
                    }
                    yes.x = display.contentWidth*0.3
                    yes.y = display.contentHeight - 200

                    local function hindi()
                        if isPaused == true then
                        physics.start()
                        isPaused = false
                            timer.resume(countDownTimer)

                            display.remove(decide)
                            decide = nil
                            display.remove(yes)
                            yes = nil
                            display.remove(no)
                            no = nil
                            end
                        return true
                    end

                    no = widget.newButton
                    {
                        defaultFile= "no.png",
                        width=100, height=50,
                        onRelease = hindi   
                    }
                    no.x = display.contentWidth*0.7
                    no.y = display.contentHeight - 200

                    sceneGroup:insert(decide)
                    sceneGroup:insert(yes)
                    sceneGroup:insert(no)
            return true
            end
        end
    end

local function tapos(event)
    if (event.phase == "began") then
        physics.addBody(backBtn, "static")

    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", backBtn)
backBtn:addEventListener("touch", pausePhysics)

local function ulit()
    local mRandom = math.random
    local balloon = { ("blue.png"), ("green.png"), ("red.png"), ("orange.png"), ("pink.png"), ("violet.png"), ("yellow.png"), ("blue2.png"), ("green2.png"), ("red2.png"), ("orange2.png"), ("pink2.png"), ("violet2.png"), ("yellow2.png") }
    local lobo = display.newImage( balloon[mRandom(10)], mRandom(30,270), mRandom(550,650) )
    physics.addBody( lobo, { density=0.1, friction=2.0, bounce=0.0, velocity=-40, isSensor=true } );

end

timer.performWithDelay(300,ulit,0)
```

Comment: Use [`physics.pause()`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/pause.html) instead of `physics.pause(lobo)`.  [Timer](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/timer/index.html) on end of your code runs in infinity loop and it works even you get to another scene. You should stop/pause it.

Comment: @ldurniat , nothing happens sir.

Comment: I solved it :) ... I create a variable which holds the loop of `function ulit()` then put it inside `timer.pause()` . Anyway, thanks again sir @Idurniat :)